# Removing default ui-router state then nested state is active in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

This is probably an easy answer, but I am having difficulty wrapping my brain around it. I am building an Angular dashboard and once logged in, users can browser to /dashboard; I also have nested states for browsing around the dashboard.  Below is how my states are setup (shortened for brevity)

**app.js**

```
.state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
})
.state('dashboard.new', {
      url: '/new',
      templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.new.html'
});
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<div page-header></div>
<div dashboard-menu></div>
<section>
    <div class="container mt48">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <h4 class="uppercase mb16">This is the dashboard default page</h4>

                <p class="lead mb64">
                    FSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut
                    odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Although not pertaining to this question, I've created two directives for the page-header and dashboard-menu (just in case you wondered what that was)

**browser view:** (Edited to add another screenshot of entire header)
[image]
[image]

[image]

What I would like to know how to do is when an active state is activated - in this example, dashboard/new that the default content on the /dashboard page will not be shown.

Thank you for taking a look - please ask me anything as I know what I was trying to ask and am hopeful I did without being confusing.  Thank you.

Comment: Is the whole view different or do you just want to hide a little bit of it? You might not need a nested view if you don't need actual nesting. Or, move the header bit to a nested view of it's own inside dashboard.

Comment: Jorg, I guess I should have included the entire header.  I added another screenshot to the top of the image heap.  The /dashboard menu will only be viewable once logged in...all other menu's in dashboard will be nested.

Comment: maybe just an `ng-show` on the /dashboard default text then

Comment: Thanks Jorg...seems like the simplest solutions are illusive at times :)
I ended up using `ng-show="$state.is('dashboard')"` for the section I wanted to show only on the dashboard and I added `$scope.$state= $state;` in my controller.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please add an official answer from the response in your comment so I can check it as solved?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way I think would be to hide the default text with `ng-show`. State can be determined by the `$state` object. Alternatively, perhaps it can be injected through the `resolve` function of the route itself.